# window.open() having issues in mozzilla and IE but works in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

Ok, so simple. I'm trying to open a printer friendly format containing the information on the page in a flat form in another window. The following works fantastic in chrome, but falls short in IE and FireFox. Meaning it will open a new tab but it never loads any content. Any thoughts on to why it would work in chrome and not firefox?

```
function generate_printer_friendly(){
    var form = jQ('<form/>').appendTo(document);

    window.open('','printer_friendly');
    form.attr('action','plugins/BuildAndInstall/pages/printer_friendly.php')
        .attr('target','printer_friendly')
        .attr('method','post')
        ;

    jQ('<input/>')
        .attr('type','hidden')
        .attr('name','bid')
        .val(JSON.stringify(bid))
        .appendTo(form)
        ;

    form[0].submit();
    form.remove();
}
```

Comment: version of IE, Firefox you are using ??

Comment: IE 9.0.8112.16421, 16.0.2 mozzila

Comment: In Firefox *Tools > Web Developer >* **Web Console** would help you to find some hints about the issue you're having.

Comment: What exactly is "falls short in IE and FireFox"? Popupblocker? Errors in the console? Anything else noteworthy?

Comment: Thanks for the comment G. Kayaalp but I'm not even sure how this would help me at this point. Nothing is displayed to the console. While the page opens the content never loads within the page. So it also never prints anything out to the console.

Comment: @Christoph It opens a new tab but no content ever gets loaded to the new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the form to `$("body")` and not to `document`. Otherwise, your form will not be posted correctly.